# What are the uses of arbitrary length output hashes (other than OAEP)?

Tags: hash, keccak, oaep

Functions such as [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) from the Keccak family allow for a hash of arbitrary length output. These functions are (according to Wikipedia) useful for practical, lightweight applications.

I know that SHAKE-128 and SHAKE-256 can be applied for [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding).

My question is: Are there *currently* any other applications found for such functions?

Comment: Oh boy, that list is going to be long. A community-wiki answer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Uses for SHAKE/XOF functions

Community wiki answer, please add and edit:

- key derivation of any type

  - such as turning a 128-256 bit secret key into an ECC or RSA public/private key pair
- deterministic secure uniform random number generation starting from a small seed

  - this might be used in fuzzing tools, simulations, etc. where you want a lot of random data for your experiment but you want it to be repeatable
- stream ciphers

  - absorb the key and IV then output the key stream
- authenticated encryption

  - such as the [duplex construction](http://sponge.noekeon.org/SpongeDuplex.pdf)
- length-preserving data obfuscation or anonymization

  - One might hash all customer data from a production environment when being copied into a development environment. An XOF can presereve the data cardinality distribution as well as the *data size* distribution of the "real" production data for accurate testing and performance comparisons in non-production environments.
- digital signatures

  - digital signatures such as EdDSA employ hash functions whose output must be a specific size, some of them "awkward" (e.g. Ed448 requires a 912-bit hash function). This can be easily accomplished with a XOF. (In fact, Ed448 uses SHAKE256.)